# IE doesn't load css for .load() elements & js doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I load my content with .load() with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav a").click(function () {  
    $("#main-content").load($(this).attr("href") + " #content > *");
    return false;
   });
});
```

index.php contains the style and scripts.

The loaded content just contains the content in a div without head, body or styles.

Problems:

**- IE8 doesn't load styles & this function doesn't work:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   if ($(window).width() < 630) {
        $('aside').each(
            function(){
                $(this).parents('article').find('h2').after(this);
                    }
        );  
        }

   if ($(window).width() > 630) {
        $('aside').each(
            function(){
                $(this).parents('section').after(this);
                    }
        );  
        }
});


$(window).bind('resize', function(){

   if ($(window).width() < 630) {
        $('aside').each(
            function(){
                $(this).parents('article').find('h2').after(this);
                    }
        );  
        }

   if ($(window).width() > 630) {
        $('aside').each(
            function(){
                $(this).parents('section').after(this);
                    }
        );  
        }

});
```

I already tried to fix it like the other scripts with:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ });
```

..but it didn't work.

Any help is very apprechiated.

Answer (score 0):

Load the CSS explicitly using `<link>`, and use `$.getScript()` to load and execute the javaScript file.

Comment: The css is already linked in the head of index.php. getscript() doesn't solve the problem eather.

Comment: You are using `$("#main-content").load($(this).attr("href") + " #content > *")` which will only load DOM elements matching that selector. It won't grab the CSS (unless you used inline styles).

Answer (score 0):

Is `aside` a class?

Then you'll have to use
`$('.aside').each(` instead of
`$('aside').each(`.

The same goes for `article` and `section`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: It's because of the HTML5 elements I use on the page. With HTML5shiv it's no problem to get them running on the page generally but IE won't catch them on loaded content via .load().

Here's a topic going on about that already.

[How to "enable" HTML5 elements in IE 8 that were inserted by AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363040/how-to-enable-html5-elements-in-ie-that-were-inserted-by-ajax-call)

innershiv is already a solution:

http://css-tricks.com/6869-html5-innershiv/

EDIT: But still having a problem with the named functions.