# IE11 vs Safari 4.1.7

Tags: css

in a css file I have this code

```
mainTitle.abc {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Babylon5 Hollow";
    color: #93ff00;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

and in my html file I use it like this:

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <mainTitle class="abc">The Web is the future</mainTitle>
    </div>
</body>
```

IE11 Displays the intended text in the predefined format, but Safari does not display the text in the wanted format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "the wanted format" and what does it look like instead?

Comment: Safari 4.x.x is a very old browser - does it support custom HTML tags? Have you tried this in a current (i.e. V7+) Safari?

Comment: I checked http://www.apple.com/safari/, but there is no download link there, and the only downloads I found were NOT from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tag called `<mainTitle>` as far as I know, so this will work in newer browsers, but not older ones like Safari 4.1.x

Try changing those to the appropriate header (`<h1>...<h6>`), I'm guessing you want `<h1>` here, so use this code

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1 class="abc">The Web is the future</mainTitle>
</div>
```

And in your CSS

```
h1.abc{
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Babylon5 Hollow";
    color: #93ff00;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

See also [Why does CSS Work with Fake Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353613/why-does-css-work-with-fake-tags)

Comment: You also don't need `text-align: center` on both the `div` and the `h1`. It's probably alright *just on the heading*.

Comment: Custom HTML tags are a feature of HTML5. The code is valid for later browsers, but possible not for an old Safari like v4.x.x

Comment: Well I wanted to leave as much the same as the original, but I'll remove that because inline CSS sucks