# Why the background colors of <p> tag and <p1> tag are different?

Tags: html, css

Here the 'p' tag is covering the entire row with background color whereas the 'p1' tag is showing background color on the text only.

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#c {
  background-color: #096;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
}

#c2 {
  color: #900;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

p1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<h1>xcvxcv</h1>
<p1 id="c">xcvcxv</p1> <!-- background color isn't covering the row -->

<h3>xcvxcv</h3>
<h4>xcvxvd</h4>
<h5>sdfdsf</h5>
<p id="c">sdfdsfsfd</p> <!-- background color of this '<p>' tag is covering the entire row -->
```

Comment: `<p1>` doesn't exist, I think you wanted to write `<p>`

Comment: Be aware that `id`s must be unique for each document: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Reeno: No, the OP definitely meant `<p1>`. The whole point of this question centers around rendering differences between a standard HTML element and an unknown element.

Comment: See also: [Why does CSS work with fake elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353613/why-does-css-work-with-fake-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `<p>` tags have a default style of `display: block`, which means it will take up one row of content. If you want your custom `<p1>` tag to behave similarly (since it's not a standard tag), you will have to add your own styling like so:

```
p1 { 
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _inherit style of  `display:block`_? `p` **is** a _block-level element_, so it doesn't have to inherit nothing.

Comment: You probably mean "default style", not "inherited style". It doesn't inherit from any other element - this is assigned directly to the `p` element by the UA stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, it is. But where do you think it got the style from? I stand corrected, 'default' would indeed be the more appropriate term.