# How do I animate a CSS sidebar opening and closing in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, sidebar

I have a sidebar that is made using css `display: flex;` and a button that sets the sidebars display to `display: none;`. Currently the sidebar closes and opens instantaneously, with no animation. What i would like to happen is the sidebar pops out from the left with `transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.01,0,.77);`. The sidebar hides and shows, I just want it to animate.

I tried just putting `transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.01,0,.77);` in the sidebar CSS but that did not work. Here is the code for the sidebar the content and the js.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector('sidebar');
  var display = sidebar.style.display;
  if (display == 'none') {
    sidebar.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    sidebar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-image: url("https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/macos-13-macos-ventura-macos-2022-stock-light-5k-retina-2048x1536-8135.jpg");
  background-size: cover !important;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  padding-inline: 0;
  padding-block: 13px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.01,0,.77);
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <sidebar>
    <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
  </sidebar>
  <div class="main">
    <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">SIDEBAR</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The js seems not relate to sidebar.

Comment: My bad, wrong function. Thanks @Shou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on if you want the sidebar to *slide* or *grow*, I see two options.

Either way you just need to toggle a class in order to change a property, the transition will then kick in for that property.

I've also exchanged the `<sidebar>` tag for a regular div, since that isn't technically valid HTML. See here for more info: [Why does CSS work with fake elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353613/12914833)

---

Slide left / right.

Set `margin-left` to the negative width.

Keep in mind there may be some unintended consequences since it will be overflowing the flexbox.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar')
    .classList.toggle('closed');
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-image: url("https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/macos-13-macos-ventura-macos-2022-stock-light-5k-retina-2048x1536-8135.jpg");
  background-size: cover !important;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  padding-inline: 0;
  padding-block: 13px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.01,0,.77);
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar.closed {
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">SIDEBAR</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Grow / Shrink

Set `flex-basis` to 0.

You initially set `flex-basis` to `200px` with the shorthand `flex` property. That's what determines the width of the sidebar.

I also added `white-space: nowrap` to avoid text wrapping while animating. If that's not acceptable you may need a more complex solution to stop the bullets from wrapping.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar')
    .classList.toggle('closed');
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-image: url("https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/macos-13-macos-ventura-macos-2022-stock-light-5k-retina-2048x1536-8135.jpg");
  background-size: cover !important;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  padding-inline: 0;
  padding-block: 13px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.01,0,.77);
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar.closed {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">SIDEBAR</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap sidebar and main content by flex box.

Change `flex` of sidebar and main to show/hide sidebar.

Btw html don't have sidebar tag, you can use `<aside>` instead.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const toggleSidebar = () => container.classList.toggle('active')
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  flex: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(2);
  padding-inline: 0;
  padding-block: 13px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100dvh;
  background: gray;
  transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36, -0.01, 0, .77);
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36, -0.01, 0, .77);
}

.container.active aside {
  flex: 0.4;
}

.container.active .main {
  flex: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
  </aside>
  <div class="main">
    <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">sidebar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That leaves a big gap where the sidebar used to be. The main does not resize.

Comment: Will the sidebar cover main content when active?

Comment: no, it will push main off to the side

Comment: That will be a little different, I edited my answer.